# how set value of option of select how null?

Tags: angular

how set value of option of select how null?

exemple:

```
<select ngControl="product" name="product" [(ngModel)]="product" #product="ngModel">
    <option [value]="null">Root</option>
    <option *ngFor="let p of product" [value]="p['id']">{{ p.nome }}</option>
</select>
```

When I do this it generates string ('null') When should generate null.
I have tried in many ways:

```
<option value="">Root</option>
<option value="null">Root</option>
<option value>Root</option>
<option [value]>Root</option>
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40711751/how-select-option-of-select-manually

Comment: They are a bit different. 
In this topic I just want to set myself as null. When I set null, it became a string "null". But I solved the problem on the server side. I got it resolved now! On the other topic I want to make the option selected. big hug!