# how select option of select manually?

Tags: angular

I have the following example:

```
<select ngControl="product" name="product" [(ngModel)]="product" #product="ngModel">
    <option [value]="">Root</option>
    <option *ngFor="let p of product" [value]="p['id']">{{ p.nome }}</option>
</select>
```

I need to manually select the option. I need something like this:

```
<option [value]="" [selected]="tue">Root</option>
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[ngValue] ="-1"
[ngValue] = "p['id']"
```

You're close, I think you need to change value to ngValue

I recently asked a similar question: [Set default select list value Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40640085/set-default-select-list-value-angular2)

You need to set  the value of product to -1 in your .ts file and also set the ngValue to -1

Answer (score 1):

I have set as above and it's working for me !

```
 <option [ngValue]="product === null ? null : ''">Root</option>
```

Here on page load it compares product by null value, and after dropdown value change, it set it's value as empty string.